# Placing SVG element at onClick event

Tags: html, svg, onclick

I am currently attempting to have an onClick event in which clicking inside of a box places an SVG circle at the coordinates of the mouse pointer.

While it is *very* basic, I have managed to get the onClick event working though I cannot seem to get the circle to summon at the mouse coordinates. Instead, it is brought up in the top left of the box as if it has been given different coordinates.

Any assistance (with as much explanation as possible) would be appreciated. I am still new.

The code I have been working with is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TEST CODE</title>

<script>

var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"; 

    function showCoords() {
    var cX = event.clientX;
    var sX = event.screenX;
    var cY = event.clientY;
    var sY = event.screenY;
    var svgX = cX;
    var svgY = cY;
    }

function createCircle() {
    var myCircle = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"circle");
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"id","mycircle");
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cx","svgX");
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cy","svgY");
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"r",20);
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","black");
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","none");
    document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(myCircle);
    }                 

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div onClick="createCircle()">
<svg id="mySVG" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="400" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</svg>
<br>
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines that set your circle centre are wrong.  They should read:

```
myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cx", svgX);
myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cy", svgY);
```

Ie. remove the quotes on the variables.